# Find unique combintaions of numbers in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

There is the following task to find unique combination of numbers:

Input data and expected result:
Example 1: (1, 2), (3). Result 1: (1, 3), (2, 3)
Example 2: (1, 2), (1, 2). Result 2: (1), (2), (1, 2)
Example 3: (1, 2), (1, 2), (4, 5), (3). Result 2: (1, 4, 3), (1, 5, 3), (2, 4, 3), (2, 5, 3), (1, 2, 4, 3), (1, 2, 5, 3)

Here is the example that didn't work:

```
 for (var k = 0; k < maxLength; k++)
        {
            var resultSet = new SortedSet<int>();
            for (var i = 0; i < packs.Count; i++)
            {
                var currentSet = packs[i];
                var currentElement = currentSet.ElementAt(k);
                resultSet.Add(currentElement);

                for (var s = i + 1; s < packs.Count; i++)
                {
                    var setToTakeElement = packs[s];
                    for (var j = 0; j < maxLength; j++)
                    {
                        var element = currentSet.ElementAt(j);
                        resultSet.Add(element);
                    }
                }
                    
            }
        }
```

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: You seem to be missing (1), (2), (3), and (1, 2) from your first result. I'd also think that (3, 2), (2, 1), and (3, 1) would also be unique combinations.

Comment: After looking the __Expected results___, I think the exact requirement isn't only `unique combination of numbers`

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar the result should be array of sorted hash sets so (1, 3), (3, 1) are equals

Comment: OK, but in that case you're still missing (1), (2), (3), and (1, 2) from the first example's results.

Comment: How do you get (1) as a combination of (1,2) and (1,2) ?

Comment: @NetMage It is (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2). For sorted hash set it is equal to (1), (1, 2), (2)